# XBox One controller (USB) is detected, but sends no input events

Tags: linux, hardware, input, games, joystick

I have a recently purchased X Box One wired controller, which I would like to have available on Linux. When I plug it in, it is detected, and does show up as /dev/input/js1. (/dev/input/js0 is my Wacom graphics pad.) However, jstest receives no input events from the controller.

I've installed xpad, done `sudo modprobe xpad`,and even installed xpadneo. I've attempted turning off Steam's X Box Configuration in its controller settings to get it to work; to no effect. I've updated xpad and xpadneo to the latest versions. Holding the center button does cause it to be reported as detected by Steam; but Steam does not receive joystick or button events either.

There's no Bluetooth involved here; the whole thing is connected via USB to my front panel. Normally that makes things simpler, but as of yet I have had no luck.

Can someone with some hardware knowledge explain to me what is going on, and how I can get my system to recognize the controller? I heard that it's supported natively, but this is very confusing. Thank you!

Comment: I have a similar issue on PopOS 22.04, except that mine is detected and also properly detecting input on reboot. Sometimes, however, all of the input stops being detected even though it shows up as plugged in in lsusb. If I run a usbreset on it, it fixes the issue so input is detected. Not sure if this can work in your situation, but may be worth a shot.

Comment: It's been a while since I've asked this question and I'll have to dig it out again, but @Schmango, thank you for the response!